# Make mate 1.6 look like lucid lynx default theme

Tags: themes, panel, appearance, mate

I happened to like the way Lucid Lynx looks. This is not a lucid lynx question, I just want the panels on mate 1.6 to look like the ones of Lucid lynx. I went to the properties of the panel, but it says the colour is a system theme. -Thus I cannot manage to get the exact same look. I have copied the themes out of /usr/share/themes but I still do not get the same look.

This is strictly an question of aesthetics. I loved the theme of lucid, and just want to continue using something that looks the same. How Can i achieve this look in Mate 1.6?I am using Ubuntu 13.04

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then I made this: http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/panel.png which can now be my background to the mate panel. it looks ok, though I should change the system fonts to be more white. But I guess I'm good for now.